# What are the differences between height/width: 100% and --webkit-fill-available

Tags: css

I've been using 100% and --webkit-fill-available for long time.
Sometimes the --webkit-fill-available giving me other result than height: 100%.

Does anyone know once and for all what are the differences between them?

```
 {
   height: --webkit-fill-available
 }

 {
   height: 100%
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, avoid using prefixed properties, since they are only supported by specific browsers.

`-webkit-fill-available` is the non-standard name that WebKit browsers use for `stretch`, [a experimental feature that should not be used in production](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_width_stretch).

I guess `fit-content` would have the same behavior with the advantage of being supported by all modern browsers. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content):

> The **`fit-content`** behaves as `fit-content(stretch)`. In practice this means that the box will use the available space, but never more than `max-content` [the intrinsic maximum width or height of the content].

Finally, `height: 100%` is equal to the height of the element's containing block.

Comment: Read the documentation more carefully: "...but never more than max-content" is the difference between "fill" and "fit". The other answer gives a visual aid to the difference.

Answer (score 1):

`height: fit-content` takes the size of the children

`height: fill-available` takes the size of the visible space in the browser

`height: 100%` takes the full size of the parent. If the parent is behind the navigation bar, there will be content hidden by it.

Nevertheless, I recommend you use the [new viewport units](https://web.dev/viewport-units/) for that.

[image]